# Декомпиляция прошивки роутера

Tags: роутер, декомпиляция

Здравствуйте. Есть роутер DSL-2640U (ревизия C2). Я нашел на фтп dlink собранный образ прошивки. Как можно его декомпилировать чтобы посмотреть код ?

Answer (score 0):

У них есть исходники, не нужно ничего декомпилировать - 
[сорцы](ftp://ftp.dlink.ru/pub/ADSL/GPL_source_code/RU_DSL-2640U/RU_DSL-2640U_3-06-04-3C_GPL.tar.gz)